# When i enable Compiz, i can't close, minimize, or move the windows

Tags: compiz

I can with firefox, but i have to enable a firefox fix in compiz. But i'ts the only one. The others Compiz features are working, but if i Maximize a window, i can't minimize, move, or close it.

Comment: What window manager/desktop are you using with compiz? Did you change any settings with Compiz Settings Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You must switch on these options in Compiz Settings Menager. There are in the bootom of window.